# Attach widget to HTML

Tags: java, gwt

I have simple GWT widget, that extends GWT class Composite.

Main.java

```
 public class Main extends Composite {
  interface MainUiBinder extends UiBinder<HTMLPanel, Main> {
  }

  private static MainUiBinder ourUiBinder = GWT.create(MainUiBinder.class);

  public Main() {
    initWidget(ourUiBinder.createAndBindUi(this));
  }

  @Override
  protected void onAttach() {
    super.onAttach();
    //Some logic
    }
}
```

Main.ui.xml

```
<ui:UiBinder xmlns:ui='urn:ui:com.google.gwt.uibinder'
             xmlns:g='urn:import:com.google.gwt.user.client.ui'>

      <g:HTMLPanel>
      </g:HTMLPanel>

</ui:UiBinder>
```

How i can attach it to page by clicking some button for example? When I use something like `RootPanel.get().add(new Main());`

It doesn't call onAttach of Main. For example, i want to attach my widget in  event, that calls after user clicked button.

Comment: I've just tested your code and it **does** call `onAttach` of `Main`...

Comment: Where you try to attach this widget? I mean in what class (EntryPoint)?

Comment: In `onAttach` method I've added `Window.alert("onAttach");` and called `RootPanel.get().add(new Main());` in `EntryPoint`. It did show an alert.

Comment: Yes, it works. Can you help me with the problem, when i try to attach widget in some action/event? Not in EntryPoint class.

Comment: In event handlers it works too:

 'RootPanel.get().add(new Button("Add Main", new ClickHandler() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
   RootPanel.get().add(new Main());
  }
 }));'

Please, check if you get some errors in the browser console.